# Python re.compile against all files in directory - not searching all files

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a Python 3.7.2 script that uses re.compile to search all files in a directory and returns every line in which a particular string appears. It works fine except for two problems:

1. There are several hundred files in the directory but the script only runs against the first 25.
2. It then re-runs against the first 25 indefinitely.

Any suggestions? Here's the script:

```
import os
import re

err_occur = []
pattern = re.compile(r"An important phrase")
path = "/users/mypath/"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), encoding="UTF-8") as in_file:
            for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):
                if pattern.search(line) != None:
                    err_occur.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
            for linenum, line in err_occur:
                print(line, sep='')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Input file not found.")
```

Comment: What prints out if you put this line before the first for loop : print(len(os.listdir(path)))

Comment: Have you tried `os.walk`?

Comment: Delete the line `for line in in_file:`. You are already using enumerate on `in_file`.

Comment: @Nick - no change unfortunately

Comment: @Henry Yik - thanks, code updated above.

Comment: @Belmonte so what number is printed out?

Comment: @Nick - it prints each line in which the wanted string appears, from the first 25 files in the directory. Not sure that is what you meant though? Apologies, I'm new to this!

Comment: I meant put the line  print(len(os.listdir(path)))   right after where you define the path variable. Its to confirm how many files are in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be with indentation.

I have moved some of the code and unindented the inner for loop. Try this code:

```
import os
import re

err_occur = []
pattern = re.compile(r"An important phrase")
path = "/users/mypath/"

for filename in os.listdir(path):

    try:
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), encoding="UTF-8") as in_file:
            for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):
                if pattern.search(line) != None:
                    err_occur.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Input file not found.")

for linenum, line in err_occur:
       print(line, sep='')
```

Comment: Fantastic, that does exactly what I wanted it to. Thanks very much!